# Using files as program input when program asks for input multiple times

Tags: c, input

I have a program that asks for user input twice. I want to use files to give the program the input but can't figure it out. Since it asks for input twice I can't pipe the files to the program so this is what I'm trying:

```
./prog <in1 <in2
```

But the program crashes with a segmentation fault.

The program calls this function twice:

```
void print() {
    char buf[4096];

    read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
    *strchr(buf, '\n') = 0;
    puts(buf);      
}
```

And the input files just have a few characters in them. Help please!

Comment: How does it ask for user input? The pipe you did there just redirects stdin, and I actually don't know what happens if you specify two of them :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no `\n` in the file `in1`, then `strchr` won't have anything to find, and will return `NULL`.

Next, your code will try to dereference `NULL`, and result in a seg-fault.
That is likely the source of your trouble.

To protect against the case where `\n` isn't present, I suggest this code:

```
char* p = strchr(buf, '\n');
if (p != NULL) {
    *p = '\0';
}
puts(buf);
```

---

As for directing input from multiple files, if you're on a *nix system, try this:

```
./prog < `cat in1 in2`
```